# MVC common functionality

Tags: php, codeigniter

Currently, I'm using CodeIgniter framework for my web applications and I have faced one tricky point in my app design and I wanted to know, what is a good approach(es) to solve it.

I have 3 different objects (controllers) that could have comments. I was curious, since it is a common functionality for all of these 3 objects (read comments, write a comment, etc). So my question is: how it should be designed ? (Where to put all the common controller methods and how to handle a model methods). What is the right MVC approach for it ? How to keep it DRY ?

Comment: This is what I don't like about frameworks that treat each controller as a page. When you need to have similar functionality on many pages you have to stick it all in a base controller (which can get extremely bloated) or duplicate the code. I believe having a modular design where each _part_ of the page has its own controller is a much better approach.

Comment: You DON'T need to stick it all in a base controller.  Use a library, or a helper, or a spark.  There are half a dozen options for handling this in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you've read Phil's blog post, then = ).

If you want to share logic among the other controllers, you could probably just create a comments library, a comments model and load it for each of the other classes.

[Codeigniter Libraries](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/libraries.html)

As for your database, if you wanted to store all comments in one place, you could probably do something like this:

comment_id
comment_text
comment_relation
comment_relationId

...Where relation and relation id would reference another table and some particular piece of content.

I think this would be a good approach.

Comment: :) Thanks! I think I will stick with Libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Make the 3 controllers inherit from a base controller with those methods will do the job. 
Also having a CommentController, depending of the use case, will.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Having a base controller might not be the right approach.  What if some of the comment functionality is in a sell site, wheras other comments are in an app?  It doesn't make sense to have comment handling in MY_Controller.  A controller just for comments doesn't make sense either, since a controller is by definition (in CodeIgniter) an endpoint a user can access.

Comment: You can use template methods for the differences. If each of your comment-related actions are differents, then the only think you want to avoid repeat is the name of the method and that makes no sense. So I guess all the methods are similar.

Comment: Another option is to make your three controllers have a reference to a class that handles the "common" logic.

Comment: This is what a library is (in CodeIgniter)

Answer (score 1):

You could have a FrontController and place your common functions inside FrontController, and have other Controllers extend this FrontController. I think this will aid in some way.